# ¿Como puedo calcular la letra NIF de un DNI?

Tags: java

ENUNCIADO:

El algoritmo para obtener la letra del NIF correspondiente a un DNI consta de los siguientes
pasos:

- Obtener el resto de la división entera del DNI por 23.
- La letra es la que se encuentra en la posición indexada de la siguiente
  cadena, que corresponda el valor del residuo anterior:
  "TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKE" ejemplo: el residuo de dividir 22334455
  entre 23 es 6 y en la posición 6 de la cadena anterior se encuentra
  la letra 'Y'. (Las posiciones de las cadenas de texto comienzan en
  0).
- Hacer un programa que pida introducir números de DNI hasta que
  el usuario finalice introduciendo un carácter específico (f | F).
- Los DNI s deberán almacenarse en un array que comenzará con tamaño 1
  y deberá redimensionar, incrementándolo en una posición cada vez que
  el usuario introduzca un nuevo DNI.
- El programa deberá mostrar los NIF s con sus letras.

ENTRADA DE DNI s:

```
22334455
45678965
12123256
45678964
45678987
12123233
```

SALIDA DE NIF s:

```
22334455Y
45678965E
12123256W
45678964K
45678987K
12123233W
```

Despues del enunciado adjunto lo que tengo hecho: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c6f8488afc24f7bca1f48e767b662d4b

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);

        String[] letras = {"T", "R", "W", "A", "G", "M", "Y", "F", "P", "D", "X", "B", "N", "J", "Z", "S", "Q", "V", "H", "L", "C", "K", "E"};
        int[] valors = new int[5];
        int ocupacio = 0, i, x;
        int posicion;

        do {
            System.out.println("Introduce numeros de DNI");

            for (i = 0; i < valors.length; i++) {
                if (lector.hasNextInt()) {
                    valors[i] = lector.nextInt();

                } else if (lector.hasNext("fi")) {
                    break;

                } else {

                    System.out.println("Dada Incorrecta");
                    lector.nextLine();
                    i--;

                }

            }

            for (x = 0; x < letras.length; x++) {
                letras[x] = lector.next();

                ocupacio = i;
                posicion = x % 23;

                for (int j = 0; j < ocupacio; j++) {
                    System.out.println(valors[j]);

                    System.out.println("NIF: " + valors[j] + "-"+ letras[posicion]);
                }

            }

        } while (!lector.hasNext("fi"));

    }
}
```

Solo me queda la última parte que es redimensionar el array para que me muestre la letra junto a los DNI que yo introduzco y tampoco se juntar cada letra con cada DNI, se que hay que hacer algo con un contador pero no se como hacerlo y la verdad es que estoy desesperado, espero que me podais hechar una mano, muchisimas gracias de corazón.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, aunque la solución que me has propuesto es demasiado compleja para lo que estoy haciendo, aún estoy cursando programación estructurada con arrays simples sin matrices ni tampoco hemos hecho diseño modular, de todas formas te lo agradezco.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manejar los dígitos ingresados en un arreglo y crear un arreglo con tamaño más uno con cada ingreso no es muy eficaz, pero supongo que se trata de una tarea en que se debe trabajar con primitivos. No te costumbres.

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class Dni {

    public static final String[] letras = {"T", "R", "W", "A", "G", "M", "Y", "F", "P", "D", "X", "B", "N", "J", "Z", "S", "Q", "V", "H", "L", "C", "K", "E"};

    int[] valors = new int[0];

    public void ingreso() throws IOException{
        System.out.println("Introduce numeros de DNI");
        int indice=0;
        int consola;
        do{
            consola = System.in.read();
            // char ingresado es [0-9]
            if (consola >=48 && consola<=57){
                // crecer arreglo, agrega digito a arreglo y incrementa indice
                valors = crecerArreglo(valors);
                valors[indice++]=consola;
            }
            // 70 y 102 son [fF]
        } while(consola !=70 && consola !=102);
        String dni = arregloToString(valors);
        int nif = Integer.valueOf(dni)%23;
        System.out.println("Resultado:");
        System.out.println(dni.concat(letras[nif]));
    }

    private int[] crecerArreglo(int[] arreglo){
        int[] remplazo = new int[arreglo.length+1];
        // copiar arreglo
        for (int i = 0; i<arreglo.length; i++) remplazo[i]=arreglo[i];
        return remplazo;
    }

    private String arregloToString(int[] arreglo){
        char[] c = new char[arreglo.length];
        for (int i =0; i<arreglo.length;i++){
            c[i]=(char) (arreglo[i]);
        }
        return new String(c);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dni dni=new Dni();
        try {
            dni.ingreso();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, aunque la solución que me has propuesto es demasiado compleja para lo que estoy haciendo, aún estoy cursando programación estructurada con arrays simples sin matrices ni tampoco hemos hecho diseño modular, de todas formas te lo agradezco.

Answer (score 0):

En tu ejercicio tenias varios errores de uso de la clase Scanner. Y un lío importante con el do-while y el for de su interior.

Aquí te dejo el ejemplo que he hecho yo usando todo lo que esta bien de tu código y dejándolo lo mas simple posible

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);

        String[] letras =
                          {"T", "R", "W", "A", "G", "M", "Y", "F", "P", "D", "X", "B", "N", "J", "Z", "S", "Q", "V", "H", "L", "C", "K",
                                  "E"};
        //Creamos el array con longitud 0 para ir ampliandolo como pide el enunciado.
        int[] valors = new int[0];
        int ocupacio = 0, i = 0, x;
        int posicion;
        boolean fi = false;

        System.out.println("Introduce numeros de DNI");
        do {
            if (lector.hasNextInt()) {
                int[] arrayAmpliado = new int[valors.length + 1];

                if(i > 0){
                    for (int j = 0; j < valors.length; j++) {
                        arrayAmpliado[j] = valors[j];
                    }
                }

                valors = arrayAmpliado;
                valors[i] = lector.nextInt();

            } else if (lector.hasNext()) {
                String s = lector.next();

                if ("f".equals(s) || "F".equals(s)) {
                    fi = true;
                }
            } else {

                System.out.println("Dada Incorrecta");
                lector.nextLine();
                i--;
            }

            i++;
        } while (!fi);

        for(int valor : valors){
            String letra = letras[valor % 23];

            System.out.println(valor + letra);
        }
    }
}
```

Cualquier duda que te surja lo comentamos!